# How to fetch all in blade?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs9tq.png)

In my database, i have two id i want to fetch them in my blade. but I can only first.

Where methode is

```
public function cricketMatchScoreStatus($id)
{
   $data = Matchh::with('score')->where('id', $id)->first();
   return view('public.match_score_status', compact('data'));
}
```

By Doing

```
$data = Matchh::with('score')->where('id', $id)->get();
@dd($data)
```

[I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOM3g.png)
And doing this

```
$data = Matchh::with('score')->where('id', $id)->get();

@foreach ($data as $key => $row)
   @dd($row->score)
@endforeach
```

[I get only one data where match_id 5 have 3 player_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu761.png)

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $row)
   <td>{{ $row->score->player->player_name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

In My model

```
public function score(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Score::class,'id','match_id');
    }
```

[as expected I get all data by doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWBAM.png)

```
$data = Matchh::with('score')->get();
dd($data);
```

[But the problem is this I am getting only one data in relation to where I have 3 data inside my scores table where match_id is 5. I need to show all data In a table where the match id is 5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20uD4.png)

By doing this

```
$data = DB::table('matchhs')
        ->leftJoin('scores', 'scores.match_id', '=', 'matchhs.id')
        ->get();
        dd($data);
```

[I got all match_id and and player_id but I want to show in table only match_id 5 data not other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJsI5.png)

I want to fetch all player names in the table serialized by id

Comment: `where('id', $id)->first();` ===>>> you're only getting the first record, so your foreach array will only show that single record. Change `first` to `get` and let's see the array by dd($data)

Comment: in your controller you need to do dd($data), remove that `@` sign there. Focus on the $data you're getting. It's only 1 array, even after you used `->get()`, so ... look at your query. What are you trying to do? Which normal, raw sql do you want to execute? Convert that to eloquent. Why the `->where('id', $id)` ? If you remove that, then what is the result of your `dd($data)` ?

Comment: please check-update

Comment: `SELECT * FROM match m LEFT JOIN score s on s.match_id = m.id` which result does that give you? I'm interested in `match_id` in both tables and `id` in both tables.  Your table_names might be `matches` and `scores`, so adjust to your situation

Comment: please check-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works for me

```
public function methode($id){
$data= Score::where('match_id',$id)->get();
}

@foreach ($data as $key => $row)

@endforeach
```